# Voltage conversion +1V to -3V inside a new IC design

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, charge-pump, chip-design

I am looking for a good integrated CMOS solution for creating -3V out of a 1V supply. The -3V are just used for biasing and hence do not load the supply.

This means that the solution should be switch capacitor based (only NMOS switches and caps involved). No VDS/VGS must exceed 1V.

I tried using a Dickson multiplier with NMOS diode connected devices to create 3V from 1V and afterwards use the charge pump shown in [1] to invert it. And I tried the reverse order.

While both work isolated, they fail in either order, due to the nonideal NMOS switches.

I tried the cross coupled charge pump from [2] Fig 1 which works nicely but the VGS of the devices well exceeds 1V.

Both options do not seem to be the way to do it properly. What is the simplest working option for the given scenario?

[1] https://www.digikey.tw/en/articles/techzone/2012/apr/charge-pumps-cut-switched-converter-costs

[2] http://www.sbmicro.org.br/jics/html/artigos/vol10no3/3.pdf

Comment: An inverting boost. Did you even google your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a inverting boost converter. The easiest way of implementation is the usage of an IC like **LT1617-1**. This does exactly what you expect from the circuit. Everthing you need to run this application can be found in the [datasheet](http://www.linear.com/docs/3201).

The min. input voltage is \$1\,V\$ for the LT1617-1.
Output voltage can be up to \$-34\,V\$ at max. \$100\,mA\$.

Comment: Probably can't fit this. Note how the question has evolved